# How to link listview items to different activities in android?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, drawer

my name Adam,

I followed this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rs4LW3GxOgE to create an navigation drawer, everything is working fine, as in, I am able to slide the drawer in and out. The problem I am having is, I want to link each item in the drawer to different activities. For example, I have a button/item in my itemview  called "Main Menu", I want to link this item/button to a activity called Home Screen. Similarly, I have another item/button called "Videos" in the itemview and I want to link this to a activity called My videos and so on, with all my buttons, I have 5 buttons in total.

Sorry, I won't be able to provide any screenshots of my work because my work is on my laptop and my dad has borrowed it of me for few days but I have followed the above tutorial, so if you watch that, you will understand what I am talking about.

Basically, I want to link each item/button in my itemview to a corresponding activity. few notes;

1. My items/buttons in the itemview are stored in an array in my string xlm.
2. I am unable to extend Activity on my main class, where all the code is for the drawer because I have extended Fragment and implemented an actionbar listener..

Thanks for your time

edited:

```
   private void displayView(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new Main Menu();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new My Video();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new Pictures();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new List of goods();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new Favorites();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new Plan();
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
```

![enter image description here][1]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D7MW3.png

it won't let me post an image, please follow the above link. I have created a visual diagram of what I want to do.

Comment: Hey Adam, welcome to SO. what did you try to fix your problem? it honestly looks as if you hope someone to look into this and provide you a solution for it. SO is a Q&A site, but you need to have done and tried something. I won't follow an 11 minutes tutorial to help you (and that is not mentioning I don't code for android, so I wouldn't even know where to start)

Comment: Hi Patrice, sorry, I honestly have no clue where to start. I been for the past 3 days trying to work on this and figure out how to link the items in the itemview, it might be I am searching wrong stuff but I am not finding anything that tells about how to link items in the drawer to external activities. Sorry again, if my post didn't meet the stackoverflow standard but I honestly have no clue what to do.

Comment: Thank you for answering. As much as I would love to help you, I've yet to touch android code so I don't know. The problem at this point is that your question will probably be closed over time. People won't bother to help if you didn't try anything.  The fact you can't post images or code won't help either :S

Comment: From my java knowledge, I tried using switch cases but it failed. In case if its of any use, I am going to edited my post and post the switch case.

Comment: It will actually show some work on your part, so it gives your question a better chance of not being deleted :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply add this to each of your switch;

```
Intent nameofactivity = new Intent(this, nameofactivity.class);
startActivity(activitytostart);
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume this is your first Android app? From your switch statement I think you are trying to create a new activity by doing:

```
fragment = new My Video();
```

If you want to launch an activity, you would simply create an Intent for your activity and call startActivity for that intent by putting the following in displayView:

```
Intent myVideoIntent = new Intent(this, VideoActivity.class);
startActivity(myVideoIntent);
```

You would need to do this for each of the cases.

Comment: Hi La Dee Dah, yes, I am new to android and this is my first application that I am working on. I tried the method your suggested but its not working, it doesn't give any error but it also doesn't go to the activity. It might be I am putting my methods in wrong place. Would it be possible to take this into decision please?